# formatting the toTimeString() Method

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use the toTimeString() method to display the time in the following format

13:45 (No Seconds, No timezone)

What I reeeeeeally would like to do is hack the function to display only the hours and the minutes in separate `<span></span>` so that I can add the `:` blinking inside it as a regular clock would.

I did this for jQuerty sites, AngularJS, Typescript(Angular2), but I can't figure out how to do it in React

This is my component right now

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link, hashHistory} from 'react-router';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import 'jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min';

class SidebarContent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {date: new Date()};
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState({
            date: new Date()
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        this.timerID = setInterval(
            () => this.tick(),
            1000
        );
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <ul className="nav" ref={(c) => { this.nav = c;}}>
                <li className="city-row" ref="cityRow">
                    <p>{this.state.date.toTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false }).replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{0}).*/, "$1")}</p>
                    <p>{this.state.date.toDateString()}</p>
                </li>
                  ...
                   nav stuff in here
                  ...
            </ul>
        );
    }
 }

 module.exports = SidebarContent;
```

This gets me this output `13:45:` Close, but not quite. I can't get rid of the trailing colon and if I take it out the hours dissapear instead of the seconds. Just a hot mess

How can I manipulate the toTimeString Method to display the hh only, and then the MM only in a separate `<p> or <span>`?

If you have any other way to do this without toTimeString(), I'm open to it as long as it uses react LifeCycle and all the bells and whistles. (No sloppy hacks, please)

Here is a [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/JNONYQ?editors=1010) to mess around with the toTimeString() Method

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> If you have any other way to do this without toTimeString()

Yes , there is `getHours` and `getMinutes` . You can use them directly :

```
   var n = d.getHours() + ':'+ d.getMinutes();
```

---

```
getTime() {
 return this.state.date.getHours() + ':' + this.state.date.getMinutes() ;
}

render() {

    return (
        <ul className="nav" ref={(c) => { this.nav = c;}}>
            <li className="city-row" ref="cityRow">
                <p>{this.getTime()}</p>
                <p>{this.state.date.toDateString()}</p>
            </li>
              ...
               nav stuff in here
              ...
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, this method doesn't update the time live. Any input on that? Other than that, answer was almost perfect man!

Comment: For that, you can do something like `setTimeout(function(){ this.setState({time: new Date() }, (60*1000));` on maybe `componentWillMount()`To set a timer to change the state every minute after the component is mounted. The change in state will make the component render again, getting the new minute.

Answer (score 0):

Building of Abdennours answer I've written the following because I had 2 times I wanted to format, and it also solved the problem where a time on the hour showed as `:0` rather than `:00`

```
toTimeString(date: Date) {
    return date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");
}
```